# Переписать python на pascal

Tags: pascal

```
n = int(input())
a = []
m0 = 0
m1 = 0
ms = 0
for i in range(6):
    a.append(int(input()))
a.append(0)
for i in range(6, n):
    a[6] = int(input())
    if a[0] % 2 == 0 and a[0] > m0:
        m0 = a[0]
    if a[0] % 2 == 1 and a[0] > m1:
        m1 = a[0];
    s = 0;
    if a[6] % 2 == 0 and m1 > 0:
        s = a[6] + m1
    if a[6] % 2 == 1 and m0 > 0:
        s = a[6] + m0
    if s > ms:
        ms = s
    for j in range(6):
        a[j] = a[j + 1]
print(ms)
```

вот как пробовал на pascal, но не получается с четностью сделать

```
const s=6;
var
    N: integer;
    x: integer;
    a: array[1..s] of integer;
    m: integer;
    sm: integer;
    i: integer;
    ia: integer;
begin
    readln(N);
    for i:=1 to s do readln(a[i]);
    m:=0; sm:=0;
    for i:=s+1 to N do begin
        readln(x);
        if a[1] > m then m := a[1];
        if m+x > sm then sm := m+x;
        for ia:=1 to s-1 do a[ia]:=a[ia+1];
        a[s] := x
    end;
    writeln(sm)
end.
```

Comment: Пожалуйста помогите

Answer (score 2):

> не получается с четностью сделать

```
if a % 2 == 1:
```

это переводится на Pascal как

```
if a mod 2 = 1 then
```

Comment: Есть встроенная функция `if Odd(a)`